# how to handle table td click event in salesforce lightning controller

Tags: salesforce1-app

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#myTable td").click(function() {***     

        var column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() ) + 1;
        var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() )+1;    

        $("#result").html( "Row_num =" + row_num + "  ,  Rolumn_num ="+ column_num );   
    });
});
```

How I can handle this TD click event in lightning controller?

Answer (score 1):

In component file you can define click event function like this

```
<td onclick="{!c.tdClickHandler}">Some text </td>
```

And in controller write the handler

```
({
    tdClickHandler : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('I am td click handler');
    }
})
```

Comment: Can u please tell me how can we pass arguments like i want to pass the cell data onClick.